# Eclipse Indigo Java EE HTML Editor - CTRL + SHIFT + F -> not pretty

Tags: html, eclipse-indigo, html-editor, pretty-print

I just installed Eclipse Indigo Java EE in order to play around with `HTML5` (normally, I'm still using Galileo and doing Java stuff). Anyhow, when I open an `.html` file with the HTML editor and do **CTRL + SHIFT + F** to reformat the file, the results are really disappointing - no indentation for the head or body tags and weird indentation for a script tag (opening tag indented 1 tab, function call indented 3 tabs, closing tag indented 2 tabs).

I've checked all project and global preferences and can't see why this would be happening.

People (in this forum and elsewhere) recommend the `Aptana` plug-in, but then also seem to have lots of problems with it (crashes Indigo, compatability only with Helios, etc.).

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I bit the bullet and installed Aptana. Not fun, like so many others have reported. I still don't think things are as they are supposed to be, because when I do "open with" on an html file, I'm offered a Django (Aptana) editor, but not just a plain Aptana editor.

Anyhow, the Django (Aptana) editor does do a very good job at formatting / syntax coloring.

For those having trouble with the software install, I found the two suggestions:

- increase maximum heap size of jvm (I increased mine from 256MB to 512)
- set system property java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort to true

to be helpful.

You can do both of these by adding the following to your eclipse.ini:

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m

-vmargs
 -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true